# Framework not found StringScore_Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I checked lots of other SO questions before posting this, since I know that this is a fairly common error, but nothing I've read or tried has worked for me yet.

I'm trying to add StringScore to my Xcode project, and I've confirmed that the code works but the project will not build based on the error:

```
ld: framework not found StringScore_Swift
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So far, I've grabbed the source code from GitHub, updated my podfile with `pod 'StringScore_Swift'` and run `pod install` and `pod update` just to be safe.

Then, I dragged the `StringScore.swift` file into my project. That didn't build.

I added the entire folder to Linked Frameworks and Libraries in General. That didn't build.

I updated my Framework Search Paths in Build Settings to include recursive versions of `$(PROJECT_DIR)`. That didn't build.

I added the project folder to Link Binary with Libraries in Build Phases. No luck.

Every time I get the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running the .xcworkspace project?

Comment: I am running the .xcodeproj file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run your coca pods frameworks you need to run the `.xcworkspace` project, otherwise your frameworks won´t work.

Comment: Tried that and still not working. Are there other settings I need to change in this file or with other targets?

Comment: @adsigel, you should update your podfile and then run pod update and open the .xcworkspace project and it should work.

Comment: Still no luck. I removed `StringScore_Swift` from my pod file and all references in my Xcode project and ran `pod update`. Confirmed that the app could build. Then I added `StringScore_Swift` back to the podfile, re-ran `pod install` and `pod update`, opened the .xcworkspace project and I'm getting the same error as usual.

Comment: GOT IT! I had to re-add the framework to **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** in the project **General** settings. Thanks very much for the help.